# i just installed python on my device on vscode , and it dosn't work

Tags: python, visual-studio-code

it gives me this error (Python was not found; run without arguments to install from the Microsoft Store, or disable this shortcut from Settings > Manage App Execution Aliases.) .

note that i have c/c++ on vscode and have been working with them , i wanted t install python and i dont know whats wrong

i tried to disable python from (Manage App Execution Aliases) and it didn't work , it was one of the solutions i saw

Comment: how do you: **install Python on VSC**

Comment: if you use a Mac mention it, not everybody uses Mac

Comment: @rioV8 I doubt they're using the Microsoft Store on a Mac.

Comment: Describe how did you install your Python in detail, or is it that you only installed the Python extention on vscode?

Answer (score -2):

First you need to install [python interpreter](https://www.python.org/downloads/) for your machine, then you also need to install [python extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-python.python) for vscode.

If you're on a MAC, you'll also need to change `python` to point to `python3`

```
echo "alias python=/usr/bin/python3" >> ~/.zshrc
```

Official start document: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/python-tutorial